# Error in PHP Generator

Tags: php, csv, foreach, generator

What is the best way to inform who use my generator function if something errors occurs, instead of writing weird return or raising exception like this piece of code

```
function csv_file_generator($csvFilename, $delimiter = ";", $enclousure = '"') {
    if(($csvHandler = fopen($csvFilename, 'rb')) === false) {
        return;
    }

    while (($row = fgetcsv($csvHandler, 0, $delimiter, $enclousure)) !== false) {
        yield $row;
    }

    if (feof($csvHandler) === false) {
        return;
    }

    if (fclose($csvHandler) === false) {
        return;
    }

    return; /* Exit Generator */
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should give the function only the open filepointer and not open the file in the function. And what did you have against `exceptions`?? because that is `the best way to inform who use` And the informed person (developer) know then what to do.

Comment: Agree with @JustOnUnderMillions. Generators should not be responsible for opening the file, but just iterating throught the file

Comment: Thing about this cases: File Not exists, invalid csv format, encoding bugs ...  how do you want too catch all the possible bugs?

Comment: So like @RiggsFolly says to write this code better, I must leave in the generator only while loop and wrap in another function all the rest of che function

Comment: How about a class, that seperates the sub action (open,validate,close) in method and an method like `getGenerator()` that dows the `while()`, then in `__construct($csvFilename, $delimiter = ";", $enclousure = '"')` oben the file, in `__destruct()` close the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
class CsvFileGenerator {
    protected $fp;
    protected $delimiter;
    protected $enclousure;
    public function __construct($filename, $delimiter = ";", $enclousure = '"'){
        $this->delimiter=$delimiter;
        $this->enclousure=$enclousure;
        if(!file_exists($filename)){
            throw new Exception("file [$filename] dont exists");
        }
        if(!is_readable($filename)){
            throw new Exception("file [$filename] is not readable");
        }
        $this->fp =  fopen($filename, 'rb');
        if($this->fp === false){
            throw new Exception("cant open [$filename]");
        }
    }
    public function getGenerator(){
        while (($row = fgetcsv($this->fp, 0, $this->delimiter, $this->enclousure)) !== false) {
            yield $row;
        }
    }
    public function __destruct() {
        if($this->fp){
            fclose($this->fp);
        }
    }
}

foreach( (new CsvFileGenerator('mycsvfile.csv'))->getGenerator() as $line){
    #do some
}
```

One way to rome. :-)

Answer (score 0):

How about callbacks?

```
function gen($i, $on_close = null, $on_error = null) {
    while ($i--) {
        yield $i;

        if ($i === 5 && is_callable($on_close)) {
            $on_close();
        }
    }
}

$closed = false;
$gen = gen(10, function () use (&$closed) {
    $closed = true;
});

foreach ($gen as $x) {
    if ($closed) {
        break;
    }

    echo $x, PHP_EOL;
}
```

I'll admit its not pretty. Another options could be to return instances of special classes to let your main code know something is wrong.