# Error handling inside PHP generator function

Tags: php, exception, error-handling, generator

Related: [Error in PHP Generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39898739/error-in-php-generator)

How do I propagate errors in a generator function without stopping iteration?

Example:

```
class SynchronizeSchedules extends \Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command
{
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): void {
        $synchronizer = new \ScheduleSync();
        foreach ($synchronizer->sync() as $schedule) {
            $output->writeln("Schedule {$schedule->id} synchronized");
        }
    }
}

class ScheduleSync
{
    public function sync(): \Generator {
        $data = [/* data from somewhere */];

        foreach ($data as $d) {
            try {
                // insert into database
                $this->db->insert('...');
                yield $d;
            } catch (DBALException $e) {
                // something went wrong
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If a database error (`DBALException`) occurs, I want to do something. For example in the CLI command (Symfony Console) I'd like to write to STDOUT. When invoked in the web application, logging the error to a file or something would be more appropriate.

Apart from passing a LoggerInterface object into the class that has a generator method, is there a clean way of dealing with this?

Comment: Is passing a Logging object in _not_ the clean way? How are you implementing logging elsewhere?

Comment: @Sammitch Usually wait for the error to propagate up to the front controller or entry point to log. In this case that would stop all subsequent iterations so it isn't an option.

Comment: The next best thing I've found is to [yield the Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50838275/1064767) and then you can handle it at the end or whatever. Probably not the best idea, IMO. You need to be absolutely certain that the failed operations have no possibility of compromising your DB's integrity, otherwise log an error and rollback the transaction.